# Eclipse -> Debug -> Expressions not working

Tags: eclipse, debugging, grails, groovy

I am doing grails application, while debug my application, I want to watch some variables and expressions but sometimes Expressions not working.

I am getting some information like this

```
See error log: (Groovy) Complete snippet:
null
```

I tried, deleting all the existing expressions, and created new one, even same error message.

But sometimes it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ravi,

That's really strange, looks like a bug. I am able to replicate the same scenario if I change the groovy class and compile it and than revert back the change and compile it again. It looks like the debugger didn't recognises the change it reported the above error.

I restarted my app and it is showing the expressions values. I am using following IDE.

Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 
Version: 3.6.3.RELEASE